# How many shuffles are really needed for bridge?

Tags: reference-request, random, card-games

According to the [Gilbert-Shannon-Reeds model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Shannon%E2%80%93Reeds_model) (which apparently models reality well), one should [riffle shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Riffle) seven times to achieve a suitably randomized $52$ card deck.

However, it occurs to me that in bridge as well as many other card games, we don't care about a random order over the entire deck, but only a random order modulo $4$, since everyone is dealt a $13$ card hand (with each person receiving a card in turn).

> Given this easier situation, how many riffle shuffles necessary to achieve suitable randomness? I am interested if anyone has any resources for this specific case (and of course I would be very impressed if anyone actually goes through the analysis here).

I understand that suitable randomness is not a well-defined concept - in the Gilbert-Shannon-Reeds model, seven shuffles corresponds to a [total variation distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) of $0.334$, so I would be looking for the amount of shuffles which gives a similar number.

This question is mostly motivated by a desire to justify my laziness to fellow bridge players.

Comment: In the James Bond book that features Drax, he cheats at bridge by having little bit of information about the deal, along with good skills in the first place. I suggest you do the full shuffle. Possibly Moonraker, the book may or may not have the same title  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bond#Ian_Fleming_novels

Comment: Here in the video, the mathematics researcher specifically talks about shuffling in bridge : https://youtu.be/RIGJH12vVCY?list=PLt5AfwLFPxWLoz8cdew3MHrwfswn-HUrT&t=206   and around the 6 minute mark, he talks about the mod 4 behavior.  It doesn't exactly answer your question though, you might want to email the professor directly if it interests you.  Or send him a link to the question here, maybe he'll answer it for all of us.